# RSA fingerprint vulnerability

Tags: rsa

For example in SSH connections, is there a vulnerability risk with respect to the RSA fingerprint? If my connection is not encrypted does this mean they can sniff my password?

How can I fix it and make sure that the connection is secure?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. And: of there is a vulnerability in one of the most prolifically used crypto algorithms, why do you think it would be fixable? Why would it be fixable by you?

Comment: Lynda, what problems are you thinking about?

Comment: the risk here is my connection is not encrypted wish mean they can sniff my password

Comment: No, there is no generic vulnerability, and if there were, we'd solve it.

Comment: what does that have to do with the fingerprint?

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather unclear but I assume that you mean "Does it pose a risk to reveal a fingerprint (i.e. cryptographic hash) of your RSA (private) key?".

No, at the time of writing, there is no usable attack against a cryptographic hash functions like SHA-256 or other algorithms of the SHA2/SHA3 familiy.

Your concern is in fact part of the definition of a cryptographic hash function! Being able to compute an output `o` from an input `i`, by computing `Hash(i) = o`, without being able to somehow "de-hash" `o` to obtain `i` (it's not reversible). The only way is to try many different inputs which takes **a lot** of time.

Additionally, hash functions are not bijective, as there is an unlimited amount of possible inputs, but only `2^[Output_in_Bits]` possible outputs. Even if somebody could brute-force an input `j`, so `Hash(j) = o` this does not imply that `j = i`, as (in theory) there are many many inputs which produce `o` as hash-output.